# Javascript - check array lookahead matching

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, regex-lookarounds

I'm building a Google Slide based on spreadsheet data. Each slide will have details about a garment such as a dress or jumpsuit, but when I need to show details of tops and skirts together on one page, I run into an issue.

In the source spreadsheet, I'm using 1,2,3 notation to order the slides and if there is a secondary product, I'm using 1.1,2.1,3.1 etc so the order in the array ends up being

```
[1, 2, 2.1, 3, 4, 4.1 ] //...etc
```

What I'm wanting to do is pass all of the details for a slide to the Slides API in one call. To do this, I want to pass the "2.1" array in the call that creates the "2" slide. To do this, I need to do a lookahead on the array.

Here's the code I'm using to test and my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beren/s5s27r1u/1/) is here.

```
var foo = new Array();
var firstProduct;
var secondProduct = "";
var order;
foo = [
  [1, "one2", "one3"],
  [2, "two2", "two3"],
  [2.1, "two21", "two31"],
  [3, "three2", "three3"]
];
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  firstProduct = foo[i][0];
  if (foo[i][0] <= foo.length) {
    secondProduct = foo[i + 1][0];
    if (typeof secondProduct !== 'undefined' && Math.floor(firstProduct) == Math.floor(secondProduct)) {
      alert("Match " + firstProduct + " " + secondProduct);
      i++;
    }
    else {
        alert("No match - firstProduct" + firstProduct);
      }
   }
   else {
      alert("last " + firstProduct);
    }
}
```

As you can see it throws this error:

VM3349:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at window.onload (VM3349:59)

Comment: and what the reason behind this all? do you need a new data structure or just a dialog?

Comment: I need a new data structure. My current function has these paramaters: populateSlide(order, styleCode, styleName, styleColours, deliveryMonth, wholesalePrice, retailPrice, leftImage, rightImage, season, counter); - I would need to expand it to include the second product details.

Comment: please add the wanted data structure for the example.

Comment: Would it be best to pass an array with the second product as an extra parameter or should I do look-aheads such as: styleCodeProd1 = style[i][0] and styleCodeProd2 = style[i+1][0] ?

Comment: please add the wanted structure, then we can look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were accessing a undefined foo[i+1], you could do

```js
var foo = new Array();
var firstProduct;
var secondProduct = "";
var order;
foo = [
  [1, "one2", "one3"],
  [2, "two2", "two3"],
  [2.1, "two21", "two31"],
  [3, "three2", "three3"]
];
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  firstProduct = foo[i][0];
  if (foo[i][0] <= foo.length && foo[i+1]) {
    secondProduct = foo[i + 1][0];
    if (typeof secondProduct !== 'undefined' && Math.floor(firstProduct) == Math.floor(secondProduct)) {
      alert("Match " + firstProduct + " " + secondProduct);
      i++;
    }
    else {
        alert("No match - firstProduct" + firstProduct);
      }
   }
   else {
      alert("last " + firstProduct);
    }
}
```

This would run till the point their exists a foo[i+1]

Comment: it would be i < foo.length - 1

Comment: That definitely fixes the error. Thanks! Any idea if the way i'm doing it is efficient?